# Kafka: java client failed to send messages after x tries

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I try to send messages into Kafka from a Java application.

All I can get is "*Failed to send messages after 2 tries*":

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 2 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Kafka is running on a remote machine so I added to its `server.properties` (let's say that Kafka server's IP address is 192.168.0.1):

```
host.name=192.168.0.1
advertised.host.name=192.168.0.1
advertised.port=9092
```

The running Kafka is `kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1` so I used (I guess) the appropriate Java-client version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.0.1:9092");
  properties.put("serializer.class", "test.StringEncoder");
  properties.put("key.serializer.class", "test.StringEncoder");
  properties.put("message.send.max.retries", "2");

  Producer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new Producer<String, String>(new ProducerConfig(properties));

  kafkaProducer.send(new KeyedMessage<String, String>(
      "LOG", 
      "Yo! " + new Date().toString()
  ));

  kafkaProducer.close();
}
```

The `LOG` topic is already created. I am able to send messages into Kafka from the same machine that executes Java code using (and it works):

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.0.1:9092 --topic LOG
```

When Java code fails, nothing is logged by Kafka nor Zookeeper.

Is there a specific parameter I missed?

Comment: Your propety is wrong? properties.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.68.0.1:9092"); not is : "192.168.0.1:9092" ?

Comment: It was just a typo since I don't give here the real IP address. But thanks for the remark, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache kafka has a new producer client that is better:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:
https://github.com/CameronGregory/kafka/blob/master/TestProducer.java

Aparently your config is ok. Is "test.StringEncoder" your custom class? try yo use "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder" instead

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem, for me just restarting the Kafka server worked like charm. may be you should try restarting it once.